# Node.js+express+Passanger: Error: Implement me. Unknown stream file type!

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Здравствуйте. Прошу помощи с решением возникшей ситуации, т.к. моих знаний явно не хватает (только начал изучать nodejs)
Решил запустить простое приложение на виртуальном хостинге под phusion passenger.
Код:

```
var express = require("express"); 
var app = express();

app.use(function (req,res,next) {
  res.send("Hello");
  next();
});

app.listen(3000,function(){

});
```

На что выпала ошибка:

```
> Raw process output:  node.js:486
>         throw new Error('Implement me. Unknown stream file type!');
>               ^ Error: Implement me. Unknown stream file type!
>     at createWritableStdioStream (node.js:486:15)
>     at process.stderr (node.js:517:16)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/*путь-до-проекта*/node_modules/express/node_modules/debug/node.js:36:32)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
>     at require (module.js:384:17)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/*путь-до-проекта*/node_modules/express/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:14:13)
```

Гуглил способ решения проблемы, но ничего не нашел.

Comment: А версия node.js какая? У меня на локальной установке `node@0.12.6` все работает отлично.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev версия node-v0.12.13-linux-x64, версия express - 4.13.4. Заменил версию на [0.12.6](https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.6/), получил это: `*** ERROR ***: Cannot execute /home/***/node-v0.12.6-linux-x64/bin/node: Permission denied (13)`

Comment: Начните с нормальной установки и запуска node.js. Второе сообщение об ошибке говорить что что-то не так с самим node, а не с вашим express приложением

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спросил у хостера, оказалось, что у них запрещено создавать сокеты и app.listen не работает. @DmitriySimushev, спасибо!