# Node.js + Angular.js без Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

Здравствуйте!
Существует ли возможность запуска приложений на node+angular без express?
Все примеры связки ноды и ангуляра только с использованием экспресса.
Буду благодарен, если подскажете в какую сторону смотреть.

Comment: По-моему, это XY-проблема. Чем продиктовано желание избавиться от express?

Comment: На хостинге node.js работает через passenger. Express отказывается работать. Вот связанный вопрос по теме, который я создавал ранее:http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/520833/node-jsexpresspassanger-error-implement-me-unknown-stream-file-type

Comment: Нода установлена корректно, для роутинга пробовал использовать rooter-router из npm. Всё работает.

Comment: Прям сокеты нельзя делать? HTTP тоже работает через TCP'шные сокеты... так что, если это так, то там никакое веб-приложение опубликовать не получится вообще. Уточняйте ограничения у вашего хостера. Как они предлагают обслуживать HTTP-запросы без сокетов.

Comment: Похоже да,дело не в сокетах) Поискал еще по интернетам и понял,что не так поставил вопрос. от незнания. И похоже, что нужно писать роутер взамен express, умеющий работать со статичными файлами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле express это всего лишь небольшая надстройка над фреймворком connect https://github.com/senchalabs/connect
который в свою очередь упрощает работу со встроенным модулем http nodejs.

Для понимания можете посмотреть курс от Ильи Кантора по nodejs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILpS4Fq3lmw&list=PLDyvV36pndZFWfEQpNixIHVvp191Hb3Gg

Comment: В общем, методом тыка удалось определить, что падает приложение из-за console.log. Убрал экспресс ( он всё равно оказался избыточен для меня), заменил его на собственную реализацию+ rooten-router из npm. И всё заработало.:) Очень странное дело. Спасибо за направление, знал бы это раньше, то сэкономил уйму времени